# i am trying to send an email from my contact us page to email by php but it gives error my code and error given below

Tags: php, html

this is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>

                        <form action="send.php" method="post" class="contact-form contact_form_u" id="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control  contact_user_fname" id="user-fname" name="user-fname" type="text" placeholder="First name :" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control  contact_user_lname" id="user-lname" name="user-lname" type="text" placeholder="Last name :" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control  contact_user_email" id="user-email" name="user-email" type="email" placeholder="Email :" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control  contact_user_phone" id="user-phone_" name="user-phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone :" required>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control contact_user_message" name="user-message" id="user-message" placeholder="Message:" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn--highlight contact_btn_u" id="submit-btn" name="submit-btn">Send </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn--highlight contact_btn_u_c" id="close_contact"  type="submit">Close</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="response"></div>
                        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my php code

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    echo "error; you need to submit the form";
}
$fname =$_POST["user-fname"];
$lname =$_POST["user-lname"];
$email =$_POST["user-lname"];
$phone =$_POST["user-lname"];
$message =$_POST["user-lname"];

if (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($message)){
    echo "please fill all the fields";
    exit;
}
else
{
    mail("email@gmail.com", "company Message", $message, "From: $fname <$email>");
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your message sent successfully');
    window.history.log(-1);
    </script>";
}
?>
```

when i am click on the submit button.it's taking me to send.php page but it's gives me an error which is given below.
how can i solve it.

This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405

Answer (score 0):

Hi please change button name I think that is the problem in your code.

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn--highlight contact_btn_u" id="submit-btn" name="submit">Send </button>
```